# Asdf command not found

Tags: asdf-vm

Guys I'm trying to install asdf on my Linux Mint, I followed all the instructions and tried the installation more than once but whenever I try to use any asdf command this message appears asdf not found

[image]

Comment: Which instructions did you follow ?

Answer (score 2):

For zsh if got similar error you can fix using:

- after installing source ~/.asdf/asdf.sh
- then source source ~/.zshrc
- asdf --version

Answer (score 1):

there should be no space between your `--` and `version`.

It should be `asdf --version`
would look like

[image]

`.bashrc` should look like

[image: .bashrc]

IMP:
please share your `.bashrc`.

Comment: graças seu comentário percebi que não esta incluso no .bashrc,  eu estou aprendendo sobre programação ainda então não sei como adicionar pois o comando do github não confirma apos eu usar : . $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh

Comment: Open Home (from desktop) and make hidden files visible then you will see `.bashrc` there copy paste the lines given in the instructions. Then close your current terminal and **open a new one**. After doing that it will work. pls Select this as answer if this is the answer to your question. 

Comment: `. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh`

`. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash`
Copy these